# Waypoints.js waypoint is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm getting the console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function

FYI: It is a Blogger template, which uses XML.

I have included the files like so (only these two .js files):

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js'/>
```

My jQuery (longer scripts removed for clarity):

```
<script>
  // <![CDATA[
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      <!-- LET'S ADD SPAN ELEMENT TO WIDGET HEADINGS SO WE CAN DO ACCESSIBILITY & INCLUSIVE DESIGN -->
      $('.widget > .title').each(function() { $(this).wrapInner('<span />'); });
      <!-- LET'S ADD A CLASS TO THE MAIN MENU WHEN SCROLLING DOWN PAST THE MAIN HEADER -->
      $("#main-header").waypoint(function() { $('#main-menu').addClass('hide'); }, { offset: '100%' });
      <!-- LET'S MAKE THE PAGE LOADER GO AWAY WHEN PAGE IS LOADED  -->
      $('#page-loading-cover').delay(1500).addClass('page-loaded');
    });
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Why is it not working, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the *stand-alone* library ([waypoint](/questions/tagged/waypoint) — notice the `noframework` part), not the jQuery plugin ([jquery-waypoints](/questions/tagged/jquery-waypoints)). See [this CDN list](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/waypoints) and pick `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js`, i.e. include

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js'/>
```

instead of

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js'/>
```